# High CPU Usage of Matplotlibs Navigationtoolbar in Python 3.4 in Tkinter GUI

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, cpu, toolbar

I've just written this small line of code which gives a simple graph from `Matplotlib` into a `Tkinter` GUI.
I've recognized, that if I use the Pan&Zoom function of the NavigationToolbar, to drag my plot a little bit around, the CPU usage goes up to around 287%.

I've got the same problem in my original code but this example triggers the same problem.
It would be really nice to know why my CPU usage is so high in this case and maybe a solution to reduce the CPU usage.

I'm currently running on `CentOS Linux 7`, 64-bit, `Gnome Version 3.22.2`,
`Python 3.4.3`, `Matplotlib 2.0.2`, `Numpy 1.13.1`

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg 
import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

class window():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()


    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=100)
    self.plot1 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.plot1.set_title("Plot1")
    self.plot1.set_ylabel("Werte")
    self.plot1.set_xlabel("X-Werte")
    self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    self.y = self.x**2
    self.plot1.plot(self.x,self.y)

    self.Graph_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,self.canvas)
    #self.Graph_canvas.show()
    self.Graph_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    self.Toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.Graph_canvas,self.root)
    #self.Toolbar.update()
    self.Toolbar.pack()



    self.root.mainloop()

window()
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to know the reason for the observed behaviour? Is the CPU usage different depending on whether you embed the canvas into Tk or use pyplot for plotting?

Comment: Well would be really nice to know the reason for this behaviour and additionally a way to reduce the CPU usage. The CPU usage is high at embedding the plot into a canvas and at using pyplot for plotting

Comment: If the CPU usage is the same in both cases, it is due to the redrawing of the canvas. In matplotlib this process is a bit more cpu intensive, because a lot of things are (re)calculated for every draw of a figure, e.g. because axes limits change, new optimal tick positions are calculated etc. For a simple line plot there isn't really anything that can be optimized.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation.